# Read from istream until character sequence matched

Tags: c++, parsing, c++11, stream

Is there any elegant way in C++11 to read from an istream until a string sequence is present? Example:

The istream contains "test\r\ntest".
A delimiter sequence can be any string so the first read operation should read "test\r\n". The next read operation should read "test" because there is no delimiter sequence but the end is reached.

Writing a simple parser for that is no problem but maybe someone knows a way to do this with standard C++11 facilities (Using boost is possible).

#### Edit 1:

The linked duplicate question uses a tokenizer but that qould result in two tokens which are bost test. What I need is to read until "\r\n" or any other delimiter. So the first result should be "test\r\n" with an istream read pointer set to the character after "\r" so a new read can be performed.